# GWT and Spring: EditActivity trying to invoke persist method on a request

Tags: spring, gwt

I am making some tries with GWT and Spring Roo with a simple project. The code generation seems to work fine, except for the *EditActivity classes; in fact, in such classes I get some code invoking the persist method, i.e. something like:

```
@Override
protected RequestContext createSaveRequest(MyEntityProxy proxy) {
    request.persist().using(proxy);
    return request;
}
```

However, that request (of type MyEntityRequest) doesn't seem to have any persist method. It extends MyEntityRequest_Roo_Gwt, which extends extends RequestContext.

```
@RooGwtRequest("mybasepackage.shared.domain.MyEntity")
@ServiceName(value = "mybasepackage.service.MyEntityService", locator = "mybasepackage.server.locator.GwtServiceLocator")
public interface MyEntityRequest_Roo_Gwt extends RequestContext
```

Where should I look for the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the "push in" to remove the aspects resolved the issue.